# Is there a way to 100% self-contain libraries in an Eclipse Android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My question is fairly simple but I've not been able to find an answer or work out a solution myself. I'm using a few libraries in my projects (e.g. HoloEverywhere, ViewPagerIndicator, etc.), and I move between computers fairly often, send projects to colleagues, etc. Anytime I do this, my library references are all messed up and I have to redo them. This isn't really much more than a hassle, but I would much rather have the library references self-contained rather than having to use references to folders on the drive.

I've tried exporting the libraries to jar files and including those in the build path for the project to no avail. That's really the only thing I've thought to do, as I have no clue how else I could accomplish this. Basically, I want to be able to have a library contained in a project instead of referencing library projects elsewhere in the workspace. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Export as a jar and place in the lib folder that way it can reference itself

Comment: Like I said, I've tried that, and it results in the same errors as if I never referenced to the library project at all.

Comment: "I've tried exporting the libraries to jar files and including those in the build path for the project to no avail" -- that is because they are Android library projects, not plain JARs. On the whole, the long-term solution is to get off of the Eclipse+ADT combination, into something like Android Studio, where not only would you be pulling in these libraries via artifacts in a repository, but you have support for library modules (a.k.a., sub-projects).

Comment: Personally I recommend android studio, it's much cleaner, sure you have to learn gradle, but it makes everything else so much easier. I use it more than any other IDE. Clean, easy, still free, and very useful. And sorry I didn't catch that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I didn't realize Android Studio would allow me to solve this problem. I've looked into it a bit and didn't like the different format/look of things, but am definitely willing to transfer over. I do have one more question though regarding Android Studio. I use ant via the command line a lot to compile my projects. Will I still be able to use the same procedure to compile projects made with Android Studio even though the format seems different?

Comment: Android Studio uses Gradle as a build tool instead of ant, while you could probably get it to work, it would likely be easier to just move your procedure to Gradle